# Out of memory error despite having enough memory

Tags: ram, free

I am trying to use a Python package called [Camoco](https://camoco.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) using the CLI. 
When I run one of the commands that I need, I get

```
[LOG] Mon May 11 20:47:31 2020 - Your computer ran out of memory! This analysis needs to be done on a machine with more memory (16Gb+ recommended)
Unable to allocate 2.40 GiB for an array with shape (322643503,) and data type float64
```

We see that the array size is 2.40 GiB. So I ran `free -mh`, which shows:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       2.6Gi       4.3Gi       299Mi       782Mi       4.5Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi       1.8Gi       210Mi
```

It seems like there is enough memory, so why do I get this error? Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error message just for the failed allocation. You could have had many successful allocations before that, that used up your RAM. After the error message is shown, the memory is released, so you see lots of free memory.

I don't know how much memory or the performance you actually need, but you could try adding some swap space. This will add 2G of swap space until you reboot.

Get the swap space ready:

```
$ sudo fallocate -l 2G /extra.swap
$ sudo chmod 0600 /extra.swap
$ sudo mkswap /extra.swap
```

Now check your memory

```
$ free -mh
```

and now add the swap space to your system

```
$ sudo swapon /extra.swap
```

If you check the free memory again you should see the increase in your swap memory.

```
$ df -h
```

If you want to disable the extra swap space, for example to remove the file, you can do:

```
$ sudo swapoff /extra.swap
```